# how to list wildfly deployed http servlets

Tags: servlets, jboss, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0

how to list wildfly (version 16) deployed http servlets ? either from web console port 8080 or the cli ?
I have deployed a working example :

```
2021-04-07 19:10:28,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "h2-console.war" (runtime-name: "h2-console.war")
2021-04-07 19:10:28,719 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/h2-console' for server 'default-server'
```

this works : http://172.21.93.102:8080/h2-console/console/login.jsp?jsessionid=bf0d51b655f42eb956ba4f2bf98a1de9

is it possible to list the deployed http servlets, similar to the list of deployed EJB ?
could it be that EJB are necessarily deployed, whereas http servlets could be say switched off at startup in web.xml "load-on-startup" :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>webAllowOthers</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>trace</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

in the configuration/runtime tabs of the web console there is something for "undertow" http server sessions, but I can't find a list of servlets

configuration tab :
[image: configuration]

runtime tab:
[image: runtime]

list of deployed EJBs (it displays which jar/war additionally):
[image]

update :

Runtime -> Server -> Web -> Deployment -> deployment -> view does indeed show the deployed servlet, as in the correct answer, further to that, I'd need to call an EJB 3.0 bean from the servlet, but I have this error :

**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MFProLoginBean/remote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.MFProLoginBean.remote**

this EJB is listed in the web console of wildfly 16, and is fetchable with wget at : http://wildfly:8080//TServerXmlRpc/login/PreLoginServlet

the EJB (it seems EJB 3.0 ?) :

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.Clustered;
import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.RemoteBinding;
import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.RemoteBindings;

@Clustered
@Stateless
@RemoteBindings({
        @RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "MFProLoginBean/remote"),
        @RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "MFProLoginBean/httpremote", clientBindUrl = "servlet://${tserver.ejb3.client.address}${tserver.ejb3.client.port}${tserver.ejb3.client.url}", factory = it.company.tserver.ejb3.StatelessClusterProxyFactory.class) })
public class MFProLoginBean implements MFProLogin, MFProLoginLocal {
```

the invocation that fails in the servlet :

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

javax.naming.Context ctx = InitialContextFactory.create();
MFProLogin loginBean = (MFProLogin) ctx.lookup("MFProLoginBean/remote");

TUserSession userSession = loginBean.loginUser(authReq, new TInfoRequest(launcherVersion, descriptorVersion, environmentPath));

those variables are set in the wildfly start script :

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly

JAVA: /usr/bin/java

JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman
-Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n  -Dtserver.ejb3.client.address=jbosscollaudomfpro.classlocale.it
-Dtserver.ejb3.client.port=:8080 -Dtserver.ejb3.client.url=//unified-invoker/Ejb3ServerInvokerServlet?return-exception=true
-Dtserver.http.client.address=jbosscollaudomfpro.classlocale.it -Dtserver.http.client.port=8080  -Dtserver.jms.http.client.url=/jmsmessaging/connector
-Dorg.jboss.logging.Log4jService.catchSystemOut=false -Dlogmanager.log4jimpl.properties=tserver-log4j.properties  -DpropsDomain=

that "unified-invoker.sar" is no longer used since AS 7 ?

this seems to substitute java variables ? :

```
package it.company.tserver.ejb3;

import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.RemoteBinding;
import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.RemoteBindingImpl;

public class StatelessClusterProxyFactory extends org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessClusterProxyFactory 
{
    @Override
    public void setRemoteBinding(RemoteBinding binding) {
        String uri = binding.clientBindUrl();
        if (uri!=null && uri.indexOf("${")>=0) {
            uri = ReplacePropertiesUtil.replace(uri);
            RemoteBindingImpl b = new RemoteBindingImpl(binding.jndiBinding(), binding.interceptorStack(), uri, binding.factory());
            super.setRemoteBinding(b);
        }
        else
            super.setRemoteBinding(binding);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the web console go to Runtime -> Server -> Web -> Deployment then select the deployment you want and click "View". From there you can see the servlets from the Servlet tab on the left.

In CLI you can execute something like the following to list the names.

```
/deployment=YOUR.war/subsystem=undertow:read-children-names(child-type=servlet)
```

Or something like the following to list more details:

```
/deployment=helloworld-html5.war/subsystem=undertow:read-children-resources(child-type=servlet, include-runtime=true)
```

Comment: this works in the wildfly web console : http://address:9990/console/index.html#undertow-runtime-deployment;deployment=TServerXmlRpc.war it lists the servlets, how to test if a listed servlet is reachable, for example linux command wget of that url it gives 302 "found" on some and "404" not found on another ?

Comment: for a servlet listed as "H2Console" this works wget http://address:8080/h2-console, how to find the actual url of the servlet ?

Comment: how to set Max Request Time 15 MILLISECONDS
Min Request Time 0 MILLISECONDS
for http servlet with wildfly server (version 16) ? is it possible from /WEB-INF/web.xml (of .war) ?

Comment: is it possible to deploy "HttpServlet" servlets with web.xml like this : http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/servlet-30/servlet-hello-world-on-wildfly
on wildfly 16 I get this error 2021-04-10 20:42:15,464 TRACE [io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResourceManager] (default I/O-4) 
Failed to get path resource PreLoginServlet/ from path resource manager with base /opt/jboss6/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp3ae92316f0524924/content-2e8fc046b2b07891/, 
as the path did not exist

Comment: this path /opt/jboss6/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp3ae92316f0524924/content-2e8fc046b2b07891 actually DOES exist and it contains the exploded war, has anybody got a clue kindly

Comment: Yes you can define servlets in the `web.xml`. I don't know where that path would be coming from. It looks odd as it's "jboss6".

Comment: $ wget http://172.21.93.102:8080/Testwar/TestServlet
--2021-04-11 03:15:50--  http://172.21.93.102:8080/Testwar/TestServlet
Connecting to 172.21.93.102:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 19
Saving to: ‘TestServlet’

TestServlet                   100%[==============================================>]      19  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2021-04-11 03:15:50 (457 KB/s) - ‘TestServlet’ saved [19/19]

Comment: so it shouldn't be wildfly 16, I must have done something wrong ...

Comment: that path is my bad, misnomer, ignore it, anyways I managed to compile a "traditional" example like the aforesaid "HttpServlet" (I'm trying to migrate a legacy jboss 4) and it works fine (with wildfly 16) using the "traditional" web.xml it's fetchable from this url (which is not shown in web console btw)   <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>

Comment: I mean it doesn't seem necessary to use the @WebServlet("/Servleturl") notation, for sake of backward compatibility, for migration purpose from previous jboss 4